# javascript library to process complex 2D geometry

Tags: javascript, geometry, 2d

Is there a good javascript library for complex geometry like:
convex hull, 
polygon intersection (polygons with holes), 
polygon decomposition and
polygon merging ?

I heavily need polygon geometry, but it would be nice if there are more features...

Greetings...

Comment: I guess you meant 2d geometry?

Comment: @extropy jess, that is right.

Comment: Try JSTS: https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts

Comment: Flatten-js is also good library: https://alexbol99.github.io/flatten-js

Answer (score 3):

you can use the KevLinDev JS lib which contains a lot of 2D and 3D geometry calculation like
intersection, isPointInPolygon,...

http://www.kevlindev.com/geometry/index.htm

I think it is free.

Comment: wow... nice!! I will check it out!

Comment: That's an impressive library, but I can find no mention of a license anywhere on his site. And all the js files have a copyright notice at the top, that's not promising :(

Answer (score 2):

I have written my own library named [PolyK](http://polyk.ivank.net) for polygon computations. Currently it has polygon-point intersection, polygon triangulation and slicing polygon with a line segment.

Comment: no, you can simply go to http://polyk.ivank.net/polyk.js

Answer (score 0):

csg.js might do what you are looking for:

http://evanw.github.com/csg.js/

The project is still fresh, though.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would work but google as a javascript api for computation of geometric data on the surface of the Earth. You should be able to use a lot of its functionality without actually connecting to google maps. Have a looksee if your interested.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry.html